# How to get rid of errors while launching browser from terminal?

Tags: 16.04, bash, firefox, chromium

I have been facing problems to run the browser from the terminal. If I launch Firefox it shows below:

> (firefox:12544): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: :1:34: 
>     Expected ')' in color definition
>     (firefox:12544): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: :1:77: 
>    Expected 
>    ')' in color definition

Then I tried to launch chromium -browser the errors are more:

> [1:1:1015/225808.162350:ERROR:webthread_impl_for_utility_thread.cc(19)] Not implemented reached in virtual blink::ThreadScheduler *blink::scheduler::WebThreadImplForUtilityThread::Scheduler() const
>   [1:1:1015/225809.257010:ERROR:webthread_impl_for_utility_thread.cc(19)] Not implemented reached in virtual blink::ThreadScheduler *blink::scheduler::WebThreadImplForUtilityThread::Scheduler() const
>   [1:1:1015/225809.289346:ERROR:webthread_impl_for_utility_thread.cc(19)] Not implemented reached in virtual blink::ThreadScheduler *blink::scheduler::WebThreadImplForUtilityThread::Scheduler() const
>   [1:1:1015/225809.312381:ERROR:webthread_impl_for_utility_thread.cc(19)] Not implemented reached in virtual blink::ThreadScheduler *blink::scheduler::WebThreadImplForUtilityThread::Scheduler() const

Is there any way to resolve these issue? Please help me out. Because of my software I have to launch the browser from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s just the output that’s bothering you, you can send it into a dark oblivion by adding

```
&>/dev/null
```

to the command line. Note that this will swallow *all* output, use `2>/dev/null` instead to redirect error messages only.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no need to do that. All that errors you see is merely diagnostic messages sent by browser to stderr  output. Obviously seeing whose messages is intended more for developers, since its not "common" way to launch browser nowadays and those messages barely useful at all.

You can redirect output to /dev/null by launching browser this way

```
firefox > /dev/null
```

but i dont bother to do that, since sometimes those output can help especially in case of shutdown-hangs or crashes. Interestingly enough those output once helped me to understand why watching long Youtube videos often failed me - its turned out my /tmp was too small and it was clearly stated in console output.